# Change icon of activity in my application specific to share

Tags: android, android-activity, icons, share

I implement an app in which is one Activity designed for sharing text. Everything works fine, text is sharing etc. But if I would like to share some text, executing share action offered some applications which can handle sharing text. There is my application but shown icon is not equal of default ic_launcher. How can I change icon of my app when system offers me apps which can handle sharing text?

thanks.

Comment: your question is not clear! if your App's icon is not what you expect so check your ic_launcher icon in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your app in manifest file..

```
   <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  //---- here--put your new icon in drawable folders and change it here
    android:label="@string/app_name"  // same thing.. change your app name in string.xml file.. then, here app name will change automatically....
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 try this..

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes I finally found an answer how to do that. The main problem was, that that's two types: icon and logo. I set only logo for the activity in manifest file. After I set either logo either icon, everything work properly.